# DC.js specific tick text styling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I want to style a specific tick text, for example book F from the example here: https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/adjustable-threshold.html. I tried

```
var t = scoreChart.selectAll('g.tick text');
t.style('opacity', function(d, i){ return 0.5 if d[i] == 'F' });
```

But it doesn't work. How do I do it?

UPDATE - SOLVED

```
scoreChart.on('renderlet', function(chart) {
  chart.selectAll('g.x text')
  .style("opacity", function(d) {
  return d == 'F' ? 0.5 : 1.0;
  });
  });
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is not correct in JavaScript. It should be: `t.style('opacity', function(d, i) { if(d[i] == 'F') return 0.5 })`. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Thanks! I had gotten used to Ruby, I mixed them up :-)